# bash: ignore exit code, but retain output redirect

Tags: bash, diff

I have a script whose last line is:

`git diff --no-index -- ./a.json ./b.json > ./a-b.diff`

diff returns an exit code of `1` when the files differ, which causes my script to report an error.

How can I ignore the exit code from diff, but retain the output redirect of the content to the diff file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
git diff --no-index -- ./a.json ./b.json > ./a-b.diff || true
```

Or :

```
git diff --no-index -- ./a.json ./b.json > ./a-b.diff || :
```

Or, as long as you aren't using `bash -e`:

```
git diff --no-index -- ./a.json ./b.json > ./a-b.diff
true
```

Basically, you can use any command after the diff that you know will produce a zero (success) exit code.

Comment: Thanks! First option works a treat. I am using `-e`. For some reason I didn't think I could use the `|| true` syntax after the output redirect. That reasoning was flawed.

Answer (score 3):

Note: the reason you have to use `|| true` after a `git diff --no-index` is because you *cannot* ignore its exit code.
This has been made clearer with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

See [commit 0115e5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0115e5d929d06ad41eff83742a3e6a1e91ecc0c4) (29 Oct 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d4924ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4924ea7c3073c40b0f2cb367f21323aab9abfcd), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`git-diff.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0115e5d929d06ad41eff83742a3e6a1e91ecc0c4): document return code of `--no-index`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>
>
> Within `diff_no_index()`, we have the following:
>
> ```
> revs->diffopt.flags.exit_with_status = 1;
>
> ...
>
> /*
>  * The return code for --no-index imitates diff(1):
>  * 0 = no changes, 1 = changes, else error
>  */
> return diff_result_code(&revs->diffopt, 0);
> ```
>
> Which means when `git diff` is run in `--no-index` mode, **`--exit-code` is implied**.
>   However, the documentation for this is missing in [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).
>
> Add a note about how `--exit-code` is implied in the `--no-index` documentation to cover this documentation blindspot.